# How to write in greek with xelatex polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia, greek

I'm using TeXshop on Mac. I'm writing an article in french using Xelatex and I need to type some sentences in ancient greek, so i tried :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xunicode}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{SPIonic}

\setmainlanguage{french}

\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
```

but it does not work. Here's what I get:

> ```
> Package fontspec Warning: Font "SPIonic" does not contain requested Script
> (fontspec)                "Greek".
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-french.ldf)
> (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-greek.ldf
> (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/xgreek-fixes.def))
> (./essai.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
> Overfull \hbox (6.95477pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 20--21
> \TU/lmr/m/n/12 différent, soit à un seul centre, soit à plusieurs (épicycle). [
> ]\TU/SPIonic(0)/m/n/12 metabasis
> [1] [2] [3] (./essai.aux)
> xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without the font: /Library/Fonts/SPIonic
>
> Output file removed.
>  )
> (see the transcript file for additional information)
> Error 256 (driver return code) generating output;
> file essai.pdf may not be valid.
> SyncTeX written on essai.synctex.gz.
> Transcript written on essai.log.
> ```

I guess I have to chose another font but I don't know which font I can use to type in greek. I thought polyglossia and fontspec packages would do the job automatically.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The `ebgaramond` font has a *Greek Extended* section. I guess it should work.

Comment: I entered " \newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{ebgaramond}" but the log fil says "package fontspec error The font "ebgaramond" cannot be found. I had already got a similar message with my previous attemps to type in greek, so there must be a problem with Tex access to fonts

Comment: The name of the font family is `EBGaramond`. Did you install the font?

Comment: TeXLive says the package is installed... Do have I to do something else to get it installed ?

Comment: I don't think so (personally, I am under MiKTeX). Did you try changing the name for the exact name of the family?

Comment: I did, but I get the same message.

Comment: Just in case could you check whether the .otf file is on your system?

Comment: I found it in the system...

Comment: Strange… Launching `otfinfo -s` I did not see a Greek script, albeit I can see the Greek glyphs in Nexus Font. Maybe that is the reason?  Can you try `MinionPro`, which comes with Acrobat Reader, and does have the Greek script? (family name: `Minion Pro`).

Comment: is \usepackage{Minion-Pro}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Minion-Pro} correct ? the log file says it cannot find it either. The default extension is .sty, is it a problem ? How can I change it otherwise ?

Comment: The opentype  font family is exactly `Minion Pro` with a space, not a dash.

Comment: If i Type "Minion Pro", the log file show "MinionPro"

Comment: Maybe check in the documentation the possibilities with the exact file name (with the .otf extension)?

Comment: You definitely should not use *SPIonic*. It is not a Unicode font, so is completely useless with `xelatex`, `polyglossia`, and `fontspec`.

Comment: I did not want to use SPIonic at first but I tried because xunicode, polyglossia et fontspec did not handle automatically changing languages while they are supposed to do so. The problem is that fontspec does not find the files

Comment: I "solved" the problem using LateX instead of Xelatex with this  :\documentclass[12pt ,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\begin{document}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to xelatex, I found an easy solution to my problem by switching my french keyboard to a greek one in unicode when needed. As Xelatex is made for unicode, it works perfectly fine. I keep in my preambule

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

And I use the command `\textgreek[variant=ancient]{}`. It's very simple, actually.